# How can I mark points on an Apache Echarts chart?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have this dataset:

```
    record1 = { person: "Mike", date: new Date(someDate).toISOString(), value: 25, remark: ""} 
    record2 = { person: "Mike", date: new Date(someDate).toISOString(), value: 30, remark: "this is some text"} 
    record3 = { person: "John", date: new Date(someDate).toISOString(), value: 10, remark: "and this another text"} 
    record4 = { person: "John", date: new Date(someDate).toISOString(), value: 50, remark: ""}
```

In the end this dataset creates a chart with two lines ("Mike" and "John").
Now when the remark has text I want to show a MarkPoint in the chart at the exact position of, in my example: "Mike" 30 and "John" 10.

I think the Markpoint functionality would be perfect for this but I am struggling with the positioning of the points. This example works:

```
markPoint: {
            symbol: 'rect',
            symbolSize: 15,
            label: {
                formatter: 'D',
            },
            itemStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(70,78,86,.9)',
            },
            data: [
                { x: 70, y: 140 },
            ],
          },
```

But this positions the markers based on the coordinates. I would need something like this:

```
markPoint: {
            symbol: 'rect',
            symbolSize: 15,
            label: {
                formatter: 'D',
            },
            itemStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(70,78,86,.9)',
            },
            data: [
         --->       { x: "Mike", y: 30 },
            ],
          },
```

Is this possible in this way or is there any other approach possible?

The answer is:

```
data:[
       {coord: ['Mike', 30]},
       {coord: ['John', 10]},
     ]
```

Now I need to figure out how to handle this with dynamic data but that will be fine

Comment: Found it. Edited my initial question